# Continuously moving Aframe camera into direction of view

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I want to continuously move the view of my Aframe scene in the current viewing direction.

There seem to be two components to do this, (1) getting current viewing direction in correct format, (2) defining and updating a continuous animation with the current viewing direction of the camera.

I managed to get the camera's viewing direction using the following code:

```
        <script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('listener', {
  tick: function () {
    var position = this.el.getAttribute('position');
    var rotation = this.el.getAttribute('rotation');
  }
});
        </script>
```

How can I create an animation that moves in the camera's viewing direction, here for example with the current tilt?

I tried this for motion:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('listener', {
  tick: function () {
    var camp = document.querySelector("#cameraWrapper");
    camp.setAttribute('position', camp.getAttribute('position').add(0.1)););
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the direction of view should be in `THREE.Vector3()` type, you can get the direction like this:

```
var camera = document.querySelector("a-camera");
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy(camera.getWorldDirection());
```

Cause tick function would be executed in every render loop, if you use the component tick function to implement the movement, you may don't need an animation, just let the camera take a little step in the view direction. The code is like:

```
tick : fucntion()
{
    var camera = document.querySelector("a-camera");
    var stepFactor = 0.1;
    camera.parent.position.add(this.direction.multiplyScalar(stepFactor));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.7.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>
<title>Camera Movement</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 AFRAME.registerComponent("listener", {
  schema : 
  {
   stepFactor : {
    type : "number",
    default : 0.05
   }
  },
  tick : function()
  { this.el.components.camera.camera.parent.position.add(this.el.components.camera.camera.getWorldDirection().multiplyScalar(this.data.stepFactor));
  }
 });
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-camera  listener="stepFactor:0.01" position="0 0 30">
    <a-entity id="cursor" cursor="fuse: true;fuseTimeout:500"
     material="color:black"
     geometry="primitive:ring"
     position="0 0 -1"
     scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"
    ></a-entity>
  </a-camera>
  <a-grid></a-grid>
<a-box position="0 1 -2" color="blue" move eve></a-box>
</body>
</html>
```

I attached the component to the `a-camera` entity, so, `this.el` equals `a-camera` DOM element.

Comment: could you provide a complete example? See the edit of my post for what I tried.