# How to move around with A-Frame using Google Cardboard's button?

Tags: web, aframe

I am writing a WebVR application using A-Frame. The app is mostly tailored to Cardboard users. On the desktop, you can simply add the `wasd-controls` component to the camera in order to move around using WASD. However, I would like to be able to move the same way, only using the Cardboard button (i.e. a screen touch) instead, where the direction is determined by the camera's orientation. Is there a straightforward way of doing this with A-Frame?

Comment: Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43403936/6940428) would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you point out, `wasd-controls` is really just designed for desktop keyboard controls. I've written up a comparable [`universal-controls` component](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls), which can optionally replace both `look-controls` and `wasd-controls`. With this component, pressing the cardboard button will move the camera in the direction it is facing:

```
<a-entity camera universal-controls></a-entity>
```

Alternatively, you can define "checkpoints" and when the user gazes at them, teleport the camera. This may be a better user experience in many cases. [Demo](https://webvr.donmccurdy.com/checkpoints/) and [source](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/examples/checkpoints/index.html).

```
  <!-- Player -->
  <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6"
            universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint"
            checkpoint-controls="mode: teleport">
    <a-entity cursor
              position="0 0 -1"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03;"
              material="color: #CCC; shader: flat;">
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <!-- Terrain -->
  <a-grid></a-grid>

  <!-- Checkpoints -->
  <a-entity position="1 0 1">
    <a-cylinder checkpoint="offset: 0 1.6 0" radius="1" height="0.1" position="0 0 -5.2" color="#39BB82"></a-cylinder>
    <a-cylinder checkpoint="offset: 0 1.6 0" radius="1" height="0.1" position="3 0 0" color="#39BB82"></a-cylinder>
    <a-cylinder checkpoint="offset: 0 1.6 0" radius="1" height="0.1" position="-3 0 0" color="#39BB82"></a-cylinder>
  </a-entity>
```

Both of these options are implemented in the [aframe-extras package](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras), which adds several components to A-Frame.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic--exactly what I needed without even writing a single line of Javascript. Thanks so much!!