# aframe camera not moving in vr mode

Tags: javascript, camera, move, aframe, virtual-reality

I want in an aframe game continuous moving to the viewport of the camera. I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403936/9046625):

In my desktop browser (not vr mode) it works pretty well, but when I am switching to the vr-mode the moving doesn't work...

Here is an exampe of what i have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>360° Image Browser</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras.ocean@3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.ocean.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <!-- sky + ocean -->
        <a-sky radius="100" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ELqPrSgPbGU/Vcnw54n7Q1I/AAAAAAAAGdk/rcfkvjlMNqI/s1600/PANO_360Test09.jpg"
            position="0 -6 0 "></a-sky>
        <a-ocean width="200" depth="200" density="200" position="0 0 0"></a-ocean>

        <!-- camera + cursor. -->
        <a-camera id="camera" position="0 20 80" fly wasd-controls-enabled="false" look>
            <a-cursor id="cursor" color="black"></a-cursor>
        </a-camera>
    </a-scene>
    <script>
        // document.querySelector("a-scene").enterVR();
        AFRAME.registerComponent("fly", {
            schema: {
                stepFactor: { type: "number", default: 0.1 },
                isFlying: { type: "boolean", default: true }
            },
            tick: function () {
                if (this.data.isFlying) {
                    this.el.components.camera.camera.parent.position.add(
                        this.el.components.camera.camera
                            .getWorldDirection()
                            .multiplyScalar(this.data.stepFactor)
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

you can turn on the vr mode in the script by removing the commit

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happens when you switch to VR mode (in regards to the camera element), but trying setAttribute seems to make it work:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-move-camera

```
tick: function () {
    if (this.data.isFlying) {
        let newP = this.el.components.camera.camera.parent.position.add(this.el.components.camera.camera.getWorldDirection().multiplyScalar(this.data.stepFactor));
        this.el.setAttribute('position', newP)
    }
}
```